# Can I create Azure QnA Maker with 5 knowledge bases and Basic pricing tier?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-qna-maker

We have to create 5 knowledge bases in Azure QnA Maker for one of our applications. We need help in choosing the pricing tier.  Can we choose the Basic pricing tier but it is having maximum indexes allowed as 5?  The number of maximum knowledge bases allowed is (No. of max indexes - 1).  This way it needs to 6 indexes for us and we need to increase pricing tier.  Please confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can. Maximum number of knowledge bases based on [Azure Search tier limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity).

Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/limits):

[image]

Comment: In Azure portal, it is saying 5 indexes for Basic while creating QnA maker.

Comment: See if this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#index-limits) helps, it says `Basic services created after late 2017 have an increased limit of 15 indexes, data sources, and indexers. Services created earlier have 5`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Joy Wang, this really helps.